# Accessing a Redux store value from a reducer without control over the action creator

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router-redux

I am in an unusual situation:
On page load, let's say my Redux store gets hydrated with a basic value:

```
{ foo: true }
```

In a reducer, I am using `react-router-redux` (or any other library that dispatches actions itself, only giving access to an action type) to update my state on actions of type `LOCATION_CHANGE`:

```
...
case LOCATION_CHANGE: {
  const deserialized = deserialize(action.payload.query, **foo**);
  return { ...state, deserialized };
}
...
```

My `deserialize` function need the value of `foo` to update my state accordingly. Normally, I would add `getState().foo` to my action payload, but since this is a third-party library, I do not control the action payload. Is there an easy workaround for this problem that doesn't require me to rip out the third-party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a Redux middleware to transform the action.

You might want to look at [some of the existing middleware for intercepting and modifying dispatched actions](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md#action-grouping-and-interception).

Answer (score 1):

I accepted markerikson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47164526/2694328), but here is the middleware I ended up writing:

```
const locationChangeMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    const { foo } = store.getState();
    return next({
      ...action,
      payload: {
        ...action.payload,
        foo,
      },
    });
  }

  return next(action);
};
```

Now my reducer looks like:

```
...
case LOCATION_CHANGE: {
  const deserialized = deserialize(action.payload.query, action.payload.foo);
  return { ...state, deserialized };
}
...
```